# marmalade - Cannot find new API level symbols when building extension

Tags: android, marmalade, marmalade-edk

This is a Marmalade based question

I am building my android extension which is using symbols added in API level 16 and above.

When building it I get the "cannot find Symbol" error for those new classes.

How do i tell the MKB to take the set the new API level as the target sdk when building an extension

running following command

```
mkb AndroidNotification_android_java.mkb --rebuild
```

and i get

```
  if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
                                                               ^
../source/android/C2DMReceiver.java:216: cannot find symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change target API level from Android Manifest.xml file Make the target at highest API level available (currently 19)

Comment: Really? I don't think that is true. More likely it is the NDK version we use. [FTR the target API level defines the callbacks the app receives in certain key scenarios.]

Comment: OP wants to know where to define the target api level, as far as I know you can define it only from AndroidManifest. I am not sure what's the role of NDK in this. Can you clarify please?

Comment: I don't think the issue has much to do with the AndroidManifest.xml. More practically the latest API features are only known about by the latest NDKs. I'm guessing that you are using a definition not known about in the relevant NDK.

Comment: ohk, I now see that the question is related to EDK, not the app. Updating the NDK can solve this issue probably. If not updating the marmalade version may help too (not sure though).